# MySQL query : search keyword like % function

Tags: mysql, string, keyword

i have foo keyword in my database . but now i want to search like this

```
 Select id from table where name like '%foo function%'
```

**datatable like this**

```
-----------------
|id  |name   |
-----------------
|1   |foo    |
|2   |sourc  |
--------------
```

now i want "foo function" string which have "foo" match to database "foo" result please tell me how to do.

Comment: It's actually hard to understand what you are asking about. Can you please add some sample table data, and expected result.

Comment: please check i add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess, but perhaps you want the opposite LIKE:

```
Select id from table where 'foo function' like '%' || name || '%'
```

`||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Some dbms have `concat('%', name, '%')` instead, or `'%' + name + '%'`.

Answer (score 0):

What i can understand is that even if you type "foo function" you should get foo result in that.
If that is what you are looking for then you would have to write it like(in mysql)

```
name1=foo
name2=function

Select id from table where name like (concat('%',name1,'%') or      
concat('%',name2,'%'));
```

Or else you would have to implemet search engine like solr which provides you with fuzzy search and other functionalities

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Function

```
   CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
    RETURNS @Strings TABLE
    (   
      position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      value varchar(8000)  
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @index int
    SET @index = -1

    WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
      BEGIN 
        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
        IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
          BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
              BREAK 
          END 
        IF (@index > 1) 
          BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
            SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
          END 
        ELSE
          SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
        END
      RETURN
    END
```

Query

```
 Select id from table inner join (select value from fn_split('foo function',' '))
as split_table on table.name like '%'+split_table.value+'%';
```